# How does this microphone preamplifier work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, microphone, preamp

This preamplifier circuit is designed by Andy Collinson for dynamic microphones. I can't understand how it works.

Why is the microphone input connected to the emitter of Q1 instead of the base?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxv0VX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The input stage is a common base amplifier

Comment: Dynamic mics are low source impedance devices, which are a good match for a low input impedance input stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why the microphone input is connected to the emitter of Q1 instead of
> collector?*

I think you might mean why is the microphone connected to the emitter instead of the base of Q1. It would be very unusual to use the collector as an input but, using the emitter is quite common. It's called a common-base circuit.

If you think about a standard NPN common-emitter circuit, the input is causing a signal current to pass into the base due to the emitter being held at a fixed DC voltage below the base. Well, in an NPN common-base circuit, the same happens (a signal current flows in the base-emitter) but, this is achieved by "wiggling" the emitter (with the signal) and holding the base at a fixed DC level above the emitter.

In other words, there are two ways to achieve the same thing. So, why not feed the signal directly to the base as in a common-emitter circuit you might ask. The main difference is that the input impedance in a common-base circuit is much lower and, this might suit certain microphone types (compared to a common-emitter circuit).

As for the rest of the circuit, the next stage (Q2) is a common-emitter followed by a common-collector. And, there's overall negative feedback from Q3's emitter to Q2's base to provide a good degree of stability.

Comment: Andy is it possible to increase the gain of this preamp to +60db?

Comment: You'd need to simulate the circuit and alter some resistor values to see how far you could get before noise and bandwidth limitations restrict you too much. If the input is audio and you want a hi-fi reproduction then I think it might be pushing it too far @ElectronSurf <-- and, it also depends on the type of microphone used. A lower impedance microphone will help.

Comment: Thanks, I think there isn't much to play with except R6 and R7.

Comment: R8 defines the gain for Q2 and Q3 and not R6 and R7 even though it looks like they might. It's the effect of negative feedback around Q2 and Q3 by R8. But, I might be wrong and so, in cases like this I would recommend using a simulator.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME.